# Find an equation of the plane. The plane through the points $(2, −1, 3), (7, 3, 5),$ and $(−3, −3, −2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an equation of the plane. The plane through the points 
$(2, −1, 3), (7, 3, 5),$ and $(−3, −3, −2)$.

I got the Normal vector from $PR * PQ = < -16, -15, 10>$
and multiplied it by the inverse of the first point to get 
$-16x-15y+10z=13$ as an answer but the answer is wrong. 
Could someone tell me what mistake do I have?

Comment: I got $(-16,15,10)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track except one mistake in finding your normal vector  with your cross product matrix.

The normal vector to the plane is actually $N= <-16,15,10>$ instead of   $N= <-16,-15,10>$

You have forgotten to switch signs while expanding your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to find it.

Solve the determinant,

$$\pi : \begin{vmatrix}x -x_1 &y-y_1 &z - z_1 \\x_2 -x_1 &y_2-y_1 &z_2 - z_1 \\x_3 -x_1 &y_3-y_1 &z_3 - z_1\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

where $x,y,z$ with subscripts denote the coordinates of the given three points.

Here we have, 
$$\begin{vmatrix}x -2&y+1 &z - 3 \\5 &4 &2 \\-5&-2 &-5\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

$$(x-2)(-16) - (y+1)(-15)+(z-3)(10) = 0$$

$$-16x+15y+10z = -17$$

Answer (score 1):

When taking the cross product, the second term should be reversed, just like the determinant of a 3x3 matrix.

$$\mathrm{PR}\times \mathrm{PQ}= \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k}\\ 
5 &4  &2 \\ 
-5 &-2  &-5 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Therefore, it should be $\left \langle -16,15,10 \right \rangle$
Then the plane is $-16x+15y+10z=-17$. 
We can check that this is indeed the plane because all 3 points yield -17 on the right.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.